# Accessing to the ws socket server from LAN

Tags: php, apache, sockets, apache-config

I'm trying to access to my websocket server which runs on Apache 2.4.9 on my computer. So here is the config. Apache listens all connections from any IP addresses on 8081 port. So I can access to it using localhost:8081 or my static IP 192.168.1.1:8081. And everything is fine, I can open php webpages BUT.

There's one php file which listens to ws connections. It listens 2012 port for connections. So here is the issue, I can connect to it using localhost:2012, but cant connect using my static IP address like 192.168.1.1:2012.

Firewall has rules for incoming tcp connection from all addresses to the 2012 and 8081 ports. I have tried completely disable it. Not worked.

What should I do in this case?

Comment: Is your listener only listening on the locallost? Does it need to be told to listen on the other interfaces?

Comment: It's a ratchet websocket library on php. So the code is simply using liten(2012) method.

Comment: Can you paste some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By not putting in the second parm it's only listeing on localhost(127.0.0.1).

```
$webSock->listen(2012, '0.0.0.0'); 
   // Binding to 0.0.0.0 will bind to all interfaces and allow remotes to connect
```